# Please keep Corona away from AskUbuntu

Tags: discussion, hats, winter-bash

The new Winter Bash provides new hats, the first hat one will get are face masks.

[image]

Since Corona is a hot topic, this may create a shitstorm.

When working on Ask Ubuntu, I want to concentrate on the questions and answers, I don't want to think about Corona.

I know, political discussions are not allowed here and I don't want to start one.

Please, please, keep Ask Ubuntu Corona-free...

Comment: If you hate hats you can open the snowflake menu and choose "no hats for me" at the bottom, you won't see them anymore. If you just hate those specific hats and want them removed you will better off taking it to take it too http://meta.stackexchange.com Personally, I thought the social distancing hats were pretty funny.

Comment: Coronavirus is a hot topic, but not a political one.  Neither are "hats".  You don't want to participate in hats, you opt out.  There's no reason here, however, to complain about the hats being 'masks' or 'social distancing' - neither of which is a Political thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We are keeping Ask Ubuntu Covid-19-free, that's what the masks are for!

On a more serious note, you can trivially disable [winterbash](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/) if you don't want to participate:

[image: screenshot of snowflake menu and "no hats for me" button]

I don't understand what you mean about politics, there is nothing political here, but you can deactivate the hats and that will completely remove all this frivolity from your SE experience.

Comment: I really have to smile about the first sentence of your answer. I'll try to take the thing with more humor...

Comment: Good one @terdon